# Dynamic Time Warping for finding divergence in timeseries data

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, outliers, dynamic-time-warping

I have the time series information of various S&P500 sectors. I need to find which sectors are outliers and diverging from the bunch of sectors. As you can see in image below, in month of October, Utilities sector started diverging from the other sectors.

I had been trying to solve this problem using Dynamic Time Warping (dtw library in R) but it turned out that dtw is more about finding patterns in one sector, rather than finding patterns among the sectors. Is there any other technique which I can use to find relative performance of sectors (at any given time) to identify the divergence in the movement of sectors?

[image: Sector performance of SP500 companies]

Comment: Maybe Dynamic time **warping** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping?

Comment: Thanks! I am already using Dynamic Time Wrapping technique.